# generate wildcard subdomain self signed certificate?

Tags: openssl

Can anybody point me to some good tutorial about 
openssl and how generate correct sertificate for development
Application contain several subdomains so it shoul be wildcard subdomain certificate 
as far as I know.
I find some good tutorial here http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html
But I want real world example for several subdomains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple wildcard - then follow that very example - but instead of entering {{{public.akadia.com}}} enter {{{*.akadia.com}}}.

That should be it. Try. If it works (it usually does) for your user communtity then you are done.

If you *also* want this value in the subject alternative name as a DNS field - then you'll need to do a bit more. http://therowes.net/~greg/2008/01/08/creating-a-certificate-with-multiple-hostnames/ has a good example.

The short of it is that you need to find the openssl.conf file which came with your openssl install (locate openss.cnf) and then edit/ensure it has these entries:

```
 ....
 [ v3_req ]
 basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
 keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
 ....
 subjectAltName          = @altdns

 ...
 [altdns]
 DNS.1   = *.arkadia.com
 DNS.2   = arkadia.com
```

and then follow the instructions of akadia.com with the provisio that you pass a parameter

```
openssl req -config aboveedited.openssl.cf
```

to the openssl commands pointing to above

Comment: I'm trying configure nginx for Ruby on Rails project which has https support. It statr working with certificates but subdomain do not determine correctly. I'm generate ssl key with name *.mydomain.dev.key . So I'm not sure about filenames for ssl cert.  cause I do not create certificates before.

Comment: Assuming you have apache in front of your server, and you followed the commands of above example you'd add SSLCertificateFile <path>/server.crt and SSLCertificateKey <path>/server.key inside the Apache vhost section for that server. (and have config.force_ssl in your ruby config).